# How to display a particular word as bold in a String that is got from Web Service response?

Tags: jquery, jsp, soapui

I have a response from Web Service and a particular word has to made in bold. Kindly help me with this

Comment: Don't you know that there is a <b> tag in html?. Let the webservice return the string with <b>word</b> around the appropriate word.

Comment: Can you post how you are using the data from webservice?

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "Your String here";
//example
$('body').append(str.replace('here', '<b>here</b>'));
```

http://jsbin.com/dosec/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XML, you cannot use inline markup.